# How to append system time to a string variable

Tags: c++, string, ctime

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string NowTime;
    time_t now;

    struct tm nowLocal;

    now=time(NULL); // get the time from the OS

    nowLocal=*localtime(&now);

    NowTime = nowLocal.tm_hour + ':' + nowLocal.tm_min + ':' + nowLocal.tm_sec;
    cout<< NowTime;
}
```

When I run the program, it display nothing, can someone help me? I am totally new in programming.

Comment: Take a look at strftime, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strftime.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you try

```
cout << nowLocal.tm_hour + ':' + nowLocal.tm_min + ':' + nowLocal.tm_sec;
```

you'll see an integer, not anything resembling a time.
This is because it's the sum of five integers - the characters are promoted to integers, and then it's all added up.

The simplest fix is to not build a string at all but to output the parts individually:

```
cout << nowLocal.tm_hour << ':' << nowLocal.tm_min << ':' << nowLocal.tm_sec;
```

Otherwise, you need to convert those numbers to strings:

```
NowTime = std::to_string(nowLocal.tm_hour) + ':' + std::to_string(nowLocal.tm_min) + ':' + std::to_string(nowLocal.tm_sec);
```

or, you can use a `std::ostringstream`, which works just like `std::cout` and other streams, but writes to a `std::string`:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << nowLocal.tm_hour << ':' << nowLocal.tm_min << ':' << nowLocal.tm_sec;
NowTime = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
NowTime = nowLocal.tm_hour + ':' + nowLocal.tm_min + ':' + nowLocal.tm_sec;
```

is adding the hour, minute, and second to the numeric value of the colon symbol, since char is implicitly coerced to an int. That value is then being interpreted as a char in the string assignment operator.

Instead, you can simply output the values directly to `cout`. They will be formatted appropriately by `cout`'s stream insertion operator `<<`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string NowTime;
    time_t now;

    tm nowLocal;

    now=time(NULL); // get the time from the OS

    nowLocal=*localtime(&now);

    cout << nowLocal.tm_hour << ':' << nowLocal.tm_min << ':' << nowLocal.tm_sec;

    return 0;
}
```

If you would instead want to store them in a string, read up about [stringstreams](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream). They have a similar syntax to `cout` and can make formatting strings much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to put the result in a variable, you could output it like this:

```
cout << nowLocal.tm_hour << ':' << nowLocal.tm_min << ':' << nowLocal.tm_sec;
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://cpp.sh/556ww)</kbd>

Also, if you want to keep the variable, do this:

```
NowTime = std::to_string(nowLocal.tm_hour) + ':' + std::to_string(nowLocal.tm_min) + ':' + std::to_string(nowLocal.tm_sec);
cout << NowTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string NowTime;
time_t now;

struct tm nowLocal;

now=time(NULL); // get the time from the OS

nowLocal=*localtime(&now);

stringstream s;
s<<nowLocal.tm_hour;
s<<":";
s<<nowLocal.tm_min;
s<<":";
s<<nowLocal.tm_sec;
NowTime = s.str();
cout<< NowTime;
}
```

You cannot cas directly from int to string and you need put values into stream and then to string.

Answer (score 0):

What about using iostringstream to build the string you want?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ostringstream NowTime;
    time_t now;

    struct tm nowLocal;

    now=time(NULL); // get the time from the OS

    nowLocal=*localtime(&now);

    NowTime << nowLocal.tm_hour << ":" << nowLocal.tm_min << ":" << nowLocal.tm_sec;
    cout<< NowTime.str() << endl;
}
```

Or for the purposes of your program you could simple use std::cout which also happens to be an output stream.

```
cout << nowLocal.tm_hour << ":" << nowLocal.tm_min << ":" << nowLocal.tm_sec << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're pre-c++11 and can't use `std::to_string`. Here's a C-like way of doing it, sticking to the includes you're currently using.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

#define STR_LEN 128

int main()
{
    string nowTime;

    time_t now;

    struct tm nowLocal;

    now = time( NULL ); // get the time from the OS

    nowLocal = *localtime( &now );

    char hour[ STR_LEN ], min[ STR_LEN ], sec[ STR_LEN ];

    sprintf( hour, "%d", nowLocal.tm_hour );

    sprintf( min, "%d", nowLocal.tm_min );

    sprintf( sec, "%d", nowLocal.tm_sec );

    nowTime = string( hour ) + ':' + string( min ) + ':' + string( sec );

    cout << nowTime << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How append system time to a string?

My answer is to build a convenience function.

If you really only need hour, minute, second, then you need not use the relatively slow localtime().  (on the other hand, if you do need more, I think you should prefer localtime_r() for the conversion).

For an embedded system several contracts back, I found this conversion to be a relatively slow function and chose to avoid it. The algorithms to handle leap days, centuries, etc. appear simple enough.  I suspect I considered it slow simply because it calculates more than I needed in that application that was trying to do the conversion many times per second.

There exists a simpler (and probably still faster) approach involving modular arithmetic.  It starts the same - with a time(0) (and thus I suspect what I am doing here is 'hidden' in the localtime_r() function).  Side note 1 - on my older Dell running Ubuntu 15.10, time(0) is simply the fastest access to the wall clock, measuring about 6 or 7 ns 'typical' duration.  Side note 2 - time_t may change someday. "The time_t Wikipedia article article sheds some light on this. The bottom line is that the type of time_t is not guaranteed in the C specification."

The code I currently use to conveniently generate a time stamp string:

```
std::string hhCmmCssGet(time_t tt = 0)  // tt has default value
{
   time_t  now = ( tt ? tt : time(0) );

   static time_t     prev = 0;
   static char   hhmmss[] = "hh:mm:ss";

   if (prev != now)
   {
      prev = now;

      const int32_t CST = -6;
      int64_t  hr = ((now / 3600) % 24) + CST; //  hr of day, CST offset
      if (hr < 0) hr += 24;
      uint64_t min = ((now / 60)   % 60); // min of day
      uint64_t sec =  (now % 60);         // sec of day

      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << std::dec
         << std::setfill('0')  << std::setw(2) << hr   << ":"
         << std::setfill('0')  << std::setw(2) << min  << ":"
         << std::setfill('0')  << std::setw(2) << sec;

      for (size_t i=0; i<8; i++)  // transfer new value
         hhmmss[i] = ss.str()[i]; // into static hhmmss
   }
   std::string retVal(hhmmss);
   return(retVal);           
}
```

The static items and "if (prev != now)" clause, allow this function to be invoked thousands of times per second ... with much reduced effort. The second, after all, only updates 1ce per second.  And note that the std::stringstream stuff and modular arithmetic operations only run 1ce per second.

Comment: Thus, "string NowTime ( hhCmmCssGet() );" should work for you.